# Create Two Activities. - Activity One will have a TextView and a Button. - Activity Two will have a TextField ( EditText ) and a Button

Tags: android

Hello I have some problem. can anybody help me

- Create Two Activities.

  - Activity One will have a TextView and a Button.
  - Activity Two will have a TextField ( EditText ) and a Button.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? What have you aleready tried? What i can see for now is just an assignement (probably homework, so you forgot a `homework` tag) and 0% of your invention.

Comment: Did you declare second activity in your manifest?

Comment: The application has stop unexpectedly...

Comment: That's not the exception. Use adb logcat to get the stacktrace of the exception

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the intent that was passed into `onActivityResult`.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 1)
    {
        String str = data.getExtras().getString("name");
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t.setText(str);
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = data.getExtras().getString("name");
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
t.setText(str);
```

try this, don't call getIntent() again.

Answer (score 1):

Potential issues:

1. editText1 doesn't exist in your SecondActivity. Maybe it is called something else?
2. getIntent() should not be used in One because that returns the intent used to start the activity and not the result data. As goto10 suggests, data is the correct intent to be using in onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0):

1. From Activity one call second activity by startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode)
2. In activity 2,  call setResult (int resultCode, Intent data) and put the textview value    into data  and then finish().
3. In activity 1 ,Override method onActivityResult and check whehter request and result code are matching with resultCode from setResult(int resultCode, Intent data) inactivity 2.
4. get the value from data and set it to the textview in activity1.

Comment: kindly you can write code for both activities, i am not getting you.

Answer (score 0):

In Activity One, you will want to call Activity Two by using startActivityWithResult() like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_TWO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then in Activity Two, you'll send back the result when finishing the activity:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("ACTIVITY_TWO_KEY", "Here is your value");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

Then back in Activity One, you'll want to override onActivityResult like so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (REQUEST_CODE) {
    case ACTIVITY_TWO_REQUEST_CODE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //Load your text into your TextView from Activity Two
        }
        break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: I am getting a error on startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_TWO_REQUEST_CODE); Actually i am not getting what is Activity_two_request_code ? it is variable or string?

Comment: It seems that you are very new to Android. I suggest you read the official document and try it yourself first. The ACTIVITY_TWO_REQUEST_CODE is an constant non-negative integer defined by you, so you know who requests the result.

Comment: yes i am very new in android. I will declare a string ACTIVITY_TWO_REQUEST_CODE and then i can use it?

Comment: yes, it should be defined by you. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Comment: Nope, not a string ,but an int, and the value should be non-negative. In most cases, you could simply let it be 0.