# Create Two Activities. - Activity One will have a TextView and a Button. - Activity Two will have a TextField ( EditText ) and a Button

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Two Activities. - Activity One will have a TextView and a Button. - Activity Two will have a TextField ( EditText ) and a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877266/create-two-activities-activity-one-will-have-a-textview-and-a-button-activ)

Create Two Activities.

When I enter the data in second activity and press the button, I get an exception. Any help would be appreciated.